# Why does not the copmonent reevaluate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

Here is my component TodoItem.js. It receives an array with todos objects and return list of todo items. There are 2 types of todos: active and completed. Parent component sends only that type which the user choose. On click on the Todo it adds this todo to the completed array by lifting state up through executing function or uncompletes todo and adds to the actives back by the same way.
**So what is a problem?** When the todo is clicked behind the scenes it moves to the another array but it does not disappear from the screen until I type something in input or something else

```
import React from 'react'
import './todoItems.css'

const TodoItem = ({ data, completeItem, uncompleteItem }) => {
    const handleClickOnTodo = item => {
       if (item.status === 'Active') completeItem(item) 
       if (item.status === 'Completed') uncompleteItem(item)
    }

    if (data.length === 0) return null
    console.log('TODOITEMS.JS')
    return (
        <ul className='ul'>
            {data.map((item, id) => {
                return (
                    <li key={id} onClick={() => handleClickOnTodo(item)} className={item.status}>
                        {item.title}
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default TodoItem
```

Comment: if data is a state that's present in the parent component, then `data.splice(data.indexOf(item), 1)` is not the right way to update the state. Post the parent's code.

Comment: Hi, are you are mutating data on the fly? I'm asking this because if you are expecting react to reevaluate after doing that, that won't happen.

Comment: I just tried it and it does not work if I remove this line

Comment: Here is the link to the github page of this project https://github.com/nurtilex/reactTodoApp

Comment: There is a conceptual problem here, there are multiple ways to fix this, although my recommendation is to use a context. I'll share my approach shortly.

Comment: Actually... you are already using a reducer on your App.js, that's where you could store your todo list.

Comment: It is stored there already. I just passed it down through props

Comment: Noticed you just edited your code, sorry I got confused. with that change is not working either?